# How to solve a differential equation with the characteristic equation plus some conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the beginner equation

$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2} + 2\frac{ds}{dt} + 2s = 0$ with the conditions $t_0 = 0, s_0 = 1, s'_0 = 1$.

Solving the characteristic polynomial I get the solutions $\lambda_1 = -1 \pm i$

which I have incorporated in the solution $s(t) = c_1 e^{(-1+i)t} + c_2 e^{(-1-i)t}$

How do I incorporate the conditions into the final answer?

---

Edit: $s(t)$ is wrong. Because the solutions of the polynomial equation are imaginary and of special form, the correct solution involves writing $s(t)$ in terms of trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $s(t) = c_1 e^{(-1+i)t} + c_2 e^{(-1-i)t}$.

Plug in $t=0$ and $s=1$ to find $1=c_1+c_2$.

Now differentiate, and plug in $t=0$, $s'=1$. Then solve simultaneous equations.

Comment: Ah- of course. Great, I will accept this solution as soon as the minimum wait time is over.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not "wrong," but if you want to express the complex exponential in terms of trigonometric functions, use Euler's formula:
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x.$$